# boost::asio::read_until not working reliably with streambuf

Tags: c++11, boost-asio, iostream

I need help with a loop that reads XML line delimited data from a tcp source and I am encountering problems with std::getline() reading in partial lines.    In the loop, I create a `boost::asio::streambuf` into which I read via `boost::asio::read_until("\r\n")`.  Then once this has completed, I read lines from the associated streambuf.

The basic flow of my loop is shown below.

The basic idea is that the tcp data from the remote source is line oriented.  The lines that start and end `<screen>...</screen>` are XML formatted (all content from the remote TCP server are always read in on separate '\r\n' delimited lines).  Once I encounter the  line, I set a flag to capture up to the closing  line and then I wrap the lines with an XML header & parse the content.   There are some other non XML lines that I read also as shown in the else block.

This generally works fine, however during the loop I encounter partial line reads and I am not sure why.  I thought that `boost::asio::read_until` would read a line's worth of data into the `boost::asio::streambuf` response object from which I could reliably call `std::getline()`.  I noticed during debugging that getline frequently does not read in an entire line, I am not sure why this happens.

Also the the line where I test for eof() in the streambuf is sometimes true, in this case I the loop continues and I read the remaining partial line into a new stack allocated streambuf (but I am not sure if I am discarding something from the previous streambuf).  Is there some preferred way to do this, I was searching for some similar example in the boost documentation but I didnt find anything similar.  I'm also not sure if making the socket non blocking has any effect on this but I cannot do blocking calls in this particular case.

```
auto bCapturingXML = false;
std::vector<std::string> screenLines;
std::string partialLine, line;
while (!mShutdownFlag) {
    if (!socket) {
        socket = std::make_unique<tcp::socket>(ios);
        // Put the socket into non-blocking mode.
        socket->connect(endpoint, ec);
        tcp::socket::non_blocking_io non_blocking_io(true);
        socket->io_control(non_blocking_io);
        if (ec == error::connection_refused) {
            socket.reset();
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(milliseconds(500));
        }
    } else {
        // read_until we have a match to the following
        boost::asio::streambuf response;
        boost::asio::read_until(*socket, response, "\r\n", ec);
        if (!ec) {
            std::istream prosimXMLStream(&response);
            while (std::getline(prosimXMLStream, partialLine)) {
                // handle the empty line case
                line += partialLine;
                if (line.find_last_of('\r') != std::string::npos) {
                    if (line.length() > 1) {
                        if (!bCapturingXML && (line.find(
                                    "<screen>") != std::string::npos)) {
                            bCapturingXML = true;
                            screenLines.clear();
                            static const std::string gXMLDeclaration =
                                "<?xml version=\"1.0\" standalone='yes' >\n";
                            screenLines.push_back(gXMLDeclaration);
                            screenLines.emplace_back(std::move(line));
                        } else if (bCapturingXML && (line.find(
                                    "</screen>") != std::string::npos)) {
                            bCapturingXML = false;
                            screenLines.emplace_back(std::move(line));
                            // convert the screenLines to a big XML string
                            // suitable for parsing via TinyXML
                            std::stringstream ss;
                            std::move(screenLines.cbegin(), screenLines.cend(),
                                      std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(ss));
                            // reset the screenLines
                            screenLines.clear();
                            // parse the XML screen representation
                            TiXmlDocument screenDoc("screen.xml");
                            auto fileContent = std::move(ss.str());
                            screenDoc.Parse(fileContent.c_str());
                            if (!screenDoc.Error()) {
                                // get the updated page, passing in the previous one
                                handleScreenUpdate(screenDoc, vcduPage);
                            }
                        } else if (bCapturingXML) {
                            screenLines.emplace_back(std::move(line));
                        } else {
                            // capture other lines outside the
                            ...
                            line.clear();
                        }
                    } else {
                        // empty '\r\n' only line
                        LOG_INFO(gLogger, gChannel) << boost::format(
                            "%1%: empty line")
                            % __FUNCTION__;
                    }
                } else {
                    // error: partial line
                    LOG_INFO(gLogger, gChannel) << boost::format(
                        "%1%: partial line read: %2%")
                        % __FUNCTION__
                        % partialLine;
                    partialLine.clear();
                }
            }
            if (prosimXMLStream.eof()) {
                // need to re enter the loop and re-read into a
                // new prosimXMLStream
            }
        } else if (ec == error::would_block) {
            // non blocking socket mode - sleep
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(milliseconds(100));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: " I thought that boost::asio::read_until would read a line's worth of data into the boost::asio::streambuf response object " -- True, but it can also read data more than that if available at that point of time. The guarantee is that, it _would_ read upto that pattern in the input stream, but can read data after the pattern also if available.

Comment: @Arunmu that explains a lot